# Dynamically enable / disable context menu in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome Extension where I would like to have a context menu, but only have it appear on some very specific elements (such as images larger than a certain width and height). Looking at the documentation I can find only very limited filtering options.

I have tried adding / removing the context menu and disabling / enabling it in the oncontextmenu event, but this does not work immediately. The context menu is not updated until the next time it is used, but that isn't very usewful.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.